# Passar parâmetro na URL

Tags: python

Pessoal estou utilizando o código abaixo para consultar no google latitude e longitude baseado no endereço, gostaria de saber como faço para passar para a URL o endereço em forma parâmetro? O código abaixo funciona perfeitamente, pois estou passando os parâmetros fixos:

```
import urllib.request 
import json
>     
>     
>     with urllib.request.urlopen("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=140+Rua+Cica,Curitiba%C3%AD,+PR&key=AIzaSyBKP7Lndi1G9-O1NpCwV7y_QV5i7tMBx9o") as url:
>     with 
>     
>         s = url.read()
>     jsonResponse = json.loads(s)
>     test = json.dumps([s['geometry']['location'] for s in jsonResponse['results']], indent=3)
>     print(test)
```

---

Mas quando tento passar os parâmetros para URL da erro:

a= 140
b='Rua Cica'
c = 'Curitiba'
d = 'PR'

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/%/%/%/%/json?address= % a+% b,% c%C3%AD,+d&key=AIzaSyBKP7Lndi1G9-O1NpCwV7y_QV5i7tMBx9o") as url:
```

O erro:

C:\Users\Usuário\PycharmProjects\validacep\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Usuário/PycharmProjects/validacep/XXX.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Usuário/PycharmProjects/validacep/XXX.py", line 11, in 
    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/%/%/%/%/json?address= % a+% b,% c%C3%AD,+d&key=AIzaSyBKP7Lndi1G9-O1NpCwV7y_QV5i7tMBx9o") as url:
  File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: Qual erro está dando?

Comment: E corrija seu código na pergunta, por favor. Da maneira que está nem tem como entender direito o que fez.

Comment: Corrigido colega. Obrigado.

Comment: Pode ter espaços na URL, teria como printar e postar aqui?

Answer (score 0):

Em Python 3.x use: `urllib.parse.quote_plus()`

Exemplo:

```
import urllib.request
import json

def acessar(endereco):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={urllib.parse.quote_plus(endereco)},+PR&key=AIzaSyBKP7Lndi1G9-O1NpCwV7y_QV5i7tMBx9o") as url:
        s = url.read()
        jsonResponse = json.loads(s)
        test = json.dumps([s['geometry']['location'] for s in jsonResponse['results']], indent=3)
        print(test)

a = '140'      #número
b = 'Rua Cica' #rua
c = 'Curitiba' #cidade
d = 'PR'       #estado

acessar(a+b+c+d)
```

Se não quiser utilizar nenhuma API faça assim:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://www.google.com/maps/search/"+urllib.parse.quote_plus(endereco))
if resp.status_code == 200:
     conteudo = str(resp.content) #pega o conteudo html do site e transforma em string
     lat_long = conteudo[conteudo.index("staticmap?center=")+17:conteudo.index("&amp;zoom=")].replace("%2C"," ").split()
     print(lat_long[0],lat_long[1])
```